# Using Count_if on user input

Tags: c++, std

What I am trying to do, is make a function that counts the number of bodies based on the track type listed within their container. Since this is looking for a certain parameter, I used count_if.

This is how the structure is set up.

```
struct body{
    string name;
    string cartype;
    string tracktype;
    string price;
    string dayfin; 
};
```

The code will ask what track type you want the algorithm to count, like DirtOval, ShortOval, and so on. However, no matter what I do, I cannot get count_if to take my user input into consideration, and need help with it. Here is my code thus far for this.

```
int sum;
cout << "What track type?";
getline(cin, tempStr);

for(int i = 0; i <inventory.size(); i++){
    sum = count_if(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), tempStr);
}
cout << "There are " << sum << " number of bodies for this type of track in our inventory." << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Look at the examples with lambda https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count
You count square of sum with the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a string to `count_if()` where a predicate is expected.  Use a lambda instead, eg (assuming `inventory` is a collection of `body` elements):

```cpp
string tempStr;
cout << "What track type?";
getline(cin, tempStr);

int sum = count_if(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(),
  [&](const body &b) { return b.tracktype == tempStr; }
);

cout << "There are " << sum << " number of bodies for this type of track in our inventory." << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the reason why I was trying to remain somewhat vague is because I know this could be used in so many more algorithms, so thank you very much for this, I've been performing mental gymnastics all day to try and figure this out.